# Random JSON file to DataStruct unmarshalling

Tags: json, go, random, unmarshalling

I want to create a Data Struct (DS) in GOLANG given a random JSON file. That is, take the JSON file's content and unmarshall it into the DS.

Looking around, I have found solutions on how to create such DS which require knowing beforehand the JSON format (Key:value pairs, types of the values, etc.). To do that, it would be also required to 'manually' enter the fields of the struct, and then unmarshall the JSON content into it. Of course, you can always create a small script that does that. However, that seems a bit unpractical, but not entirely impossible or unimplementable.

Do you know a more straightforward way to achieve this?

I think I also found something about porting the JSON's content into an interface, but I am sure (not 100%, though), that we will want to keep these data in a more static format, i.e. a DS.  Is there a way to transform this hypothetical interface to a DS?

Comment: What do you mean by a "random JSON file"?  Do you mean that the JSON files read by the application have random structure?  Or are you asking how to generate a Go type for an example JSON file?

Comment: ` Do you mean that the JSON files read by the application have random structure?`

Exactly!

Comment: If the files have random structure, then the best you can do is unmarshal to a value with type `any`: `var v any;  err := json.Unmarshal(data, &any)`.  There are more convenient options when for files that have a fixed and known structure.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

may be you can try to do this using https://github.com/golang/go/blob/e7f2e5697ac8b9b6ebfb3e0d059a8c318b4709eb/src/encoding/json/stream.go#L371